# Can I create one drop down onchange function changes value of drop down in multiple table rows one by one

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I want to change first table row drop down[client1] of first time service and activity selection and when all first row fill then reload service and activity checkbox and second time value changes in second row of table drop down[client2]without changing first row[client1] values.

Here is my code:

#### HTML

```
<select id="service" name="service" onchange="activityFromService()">
    <option value="">Select Service</option>
       <?php
           if($rowCount > 0){
             while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
               echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row['servicename'].'">'.$row['servicename'].'</option>';
             }
           }else{
             echo '<option value="">Service not available</option>';
           }
       ?>
</select>

<label>Name of activity :<span>*</span></label>

<br>

<select id="activity" name="activity" onchange="changevalueofclient()" style="width:100%">
</select>

<br>

<table id="parent" class="tdpadding">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="clientnm">Client Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <!-- data coming in table content -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="client1"  name="client" onchange="periodicityupdate(),partnername()" style="width:100%">
              </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="client2"  name="client" onchange="periodicityupdate(),partnername()" style="width:100%">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Ajax

```
function activityFromService(){
  var service = $("#service").val();

  $.ajax({
    url : "./ajax/activityFromService.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : {service:service},
    success: function(data){

      $('#activity').html(data);
    }
  });
}


function changevalueofclient(){
  var service = $("#service").val();
  var activity = $("#activity").val();



  $.ajax({
    url : "./ajax/clientchange.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : {activity:activity,service:service},

    success: function(data){
      $("#client").html(data);
    }

  });




}
```

I tried to make dynamic ids for client drop down rows but failed.

[image: My Html Structure look like]